# Android Emulator hosts file does not change

Tags: android, emulation

I am trying to edit android emulator hosts file. However when i push the changes it shows success but when I pull the file again, the changes are not there. It is same as previous. Can please anybody help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the /etc/host file like this :

There is an other way to manipulate the /etc/hosts  (You need a **Linux** machine )

Use the system.img which come from Google

## go to your Android SDK home

1. cd $ANDROID_HOME

## find the right system.img for your emulator

2. sudo mount -w system-images/android-25/google_apis/x86_64/system.img

## edit the /etc/hosts

3. sudo vi /mnt/etc/hosts
4. sudo umount /mnt

Create an emulator (from Android Studio)

1. ASD Manager
2. → "Create Virtual Device"
3. → Nexus 5X
4. → Next
5. → Tab x86 Images
6. → Nougart - 25 - x86_64
7. → Next
8. → "AVD Name" : "Nexus 5X API 25 with WLAN hosts"
9. → Finish

I have gone this way because **emulator -writable-system -avd xx** didn't work in my environment. Also mounting the system.img in my ~/.android/avd/xxxx directory didn't work anymore.